# XCode/Swift: Function to parse Bash Output to Textwindow

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a Function which parses the Output of a Bash Script to a Text Window. So far so good. It´s working most of the Time. But sometimes it could happen that some lines are not printed. It works 10 times and the 11th 1 or 2 Lines are missing. Has anyone an Idea where i could "enhance" the following Function?

```
/**
     * Performs a "asynchronous" shell exec with non blocking UI thread
     */
    func asyncShellExec(path: String?) {
        let script             = [path!]
        let process            = Process()
        let outputPipe         = Pipe()
        let filelHandler       = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading
        var output             = ""

        process.launchPath     = "/bin/bash"
        process.arguments      = script
        process.standardOutput = outputPipe

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            filelHandler.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
                if let line = String(data: pipe.availableData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    // Update your view with the new text here
                    output = line
                    // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.logger.string = self.logger.string + output
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error decoding data: \(pipe.availableData)")
                }
            }
        }

        process.launch()
        process.waitUntilExit()
        filelHandler.readabilityHandler = nil
        self.loggerScroll.flashScrollers()
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What is the difference between the first ten and the eleventh run?

Comment: Exactly nothing. Could happen after 5 Times of Executing or after 20 Times. Its completely random. And its always the same output. I tried with some sleep commands in the Bash Script and it helps. But its slowing down the execution. If  I execute the script directly in terminal there are no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dispatching to `DispatchQueue.global` is creating a race condition. There is no reason to assign `readabilityHandler` on another queue. That doesn't make the handler run on the other queue; it makes the *assignment* happen on another queue. (The handler is run on the file handle's queue in any case.) You're making it possible for the process to complete before the `readabilityHandler` is set, which is probably what's happening and creating your symptom occasionally.

It's unclear why you named this method `asyncShellExec`. It's not async. It blocks at `waitUntilExit`. Did you mean it to be async? Assuming you don't mean actually mean it to be async, this is what I think you meant:

```
func shellExec(path: String?) {
    let script             = [path!]
    let process            = Process()
    let outputPipe         = Pipe()
    let filelHandler       = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading

    process.launchPath     = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments      = script
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe

    filelHandler.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
        let data = pipe.availableData
        if let line = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            // Update your view with the new text here
            // Bounce back to the main thread to update the UI
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.logger.string += line
            }
        } else {
            print("Error decoding data: \(data.base64EncodedString())")
        }
    }

    process.launch()
    process.waitUntilExit()
    filelHandler.readabilityHandler = nil
    self.loggerScroll.flashScrollers()
}
```

I made a few other tweaks that I believe were incorrect:

- `output` is unneeded. `line` is a local variable and will be copied
- `string += string` is much more efficient than `string = string + string`
- You were calling `.availableData` twice which I don't believe is safe. (Might be, but I'm not sure this is promised in the handler; as I recall, calling `availableData` clears the buffer.) Logging it would just give you something like "16 bytes"; usually you want a base-64 dump.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me what i must change concretely to avoid this situation?

Comment: Updated. Just stop using a background queue

Comment: Yeah many thx. Works like a charme. No Missing Lines anymore. :))

Comment: But I have another question .. is it possible to change the Textcolor of the Output? Green for Exampel?

Comment: You should open a new question for that. It’s going to depend on how you’re viewing this output.

Comment: I have one more question. In my Bash Script is for Example a Function with the Name "Mountefi". Normally I would call it this way: "bash script.sh Mountefi". How to add this extra argument to the ShellExec ? Arguments is already occupied with "script".

Comment: Its a good question, but you should open it as a new question.

Comment: In the meanwhile I have a new Problem. If the Output is done my App is not responsive for 15 or 20 Seconds. But only if you start the App the first Time (no config.plist until than). If the .plist is created and you close/shootup the App it works normally. If I run it direct from Xcode the Problem doesn´t exist at the first Start of the App. Very strange behaviour. /-: